# JSP, Servlets, Spring, Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, servlets

I am new to Java programming. I have completed my training in Core Java.
Planning to learn Spring & Hibernate.
Are JSP & Servlets mandatory to learn Spring & Hibernate?
Kindly guide me on how to proceed..
I am planning to **work in Java development**. I am not sure how things work in IT company. Do we need to Code everything from scratch or will there be any existing code templates available in the company.

Comment: No, they are not mandatory. I suggest working in a console app first and migrating from there. Get the fundamentals of the language down first. That said Java Servlets are very handy for understanding and working with plain old request-response programming model.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to fully learn JSP and Servlets before Spring but you should learn a bit of how it works because you might encounter projects still using Servlets and you even might need to write one for quick tests.

Concerning Hibernate, it's a data access framework which has nothing to do with Servlets or Spring. You can learn it with without both of them.